# parse nested li inside ul and ol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-lists, nokogiri

I have a scenario in which when li comes under **ul** I need to replace it with a dot(.)  and when li comes and **ol** I need to replace it with a number.

But the problem is-

1) It is not doing for nested li

2) It is appending at the same level. Same level means as soon as it finds li it will first add **dot(.)** and then it will add **number**.

What I want

1) Whenever li comes inside ul it should add dot(.).

2) Whenever li comes inside ol it should add a number.

```
data = "<ol>\n<li>Introduction\n<ol>\n<li>hyy ssss</li>\n</ol>\n</li>\n<li>Description</li>\n<li>Observation</li>\n<li>Results</li>\n<li>Summary</li>\n</ol>\n<ul>\n<li>Introduction</li>\n<li>Description\n<ul>\n<li>Observation\n<ul>\n<li>Results\n<ul>\n<li>Summary</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li>Overview</li>\n</ul>\n<p>All the testing regarding bullet points would have been covered with the above content. Hence publishing this content will make an entry in in the selected  page, cricket page and so on.</p>\n"

    content = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(data)
    content.at('ul').children.xpath("//li").each { |li| li.inner_html="\u2022 "+li.inner_html }
    content.at('ol').children.xpath("//li").each_with_index { |li,index| li.inner_html="#{index} "+li.inner_html }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need this:

```
content.css('ol').reverse.each do |ol| 
  ol.css('> li').each_with_index { |li,index| li.inner_html="#{index + 1} "+li.inner_html }
end
content.css('ul > li').reverse.each { |li| li.inner_html="\u2022 "+li.inner_html }

puts content

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<ol>
  <li>1 Introduction
    <ol>
      <li>1 hyy ssss</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>2 Description</li>
  <li>3 Observation</li>
  <li>4 Results</li>
  <li>5 Summary</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>• Introduction</li>
  <li>• Description
    <ul>
      <li>• Observation
        <ul>
          <li>• Results
            <ul>
              <li>• Summary</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>• Overview</li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Reason of doing `reverse` -
Consider the dom:

```
<ul>
  <li>Description
    <ul>
      <li>Observation</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When you do `content.css('ul > li')`, you get in order of [description, observation]. Without `reverse`, when you run the snippet, you change the *description*, but doing so will also change the `object_id` of *observation* node. Then you changed the *observation* node which is not referenced anywhere in `content`. That's why, I reversed it and acquired `children` before parents. By doing this, I made sure I'm changing the child first and then changed the parent so *parent* was aware of the change in child and there is no unreferenced node anywhere.

Suppose description's node id is 1234 and observation node_id is 2345. When you *mutated* description, it changed itself but also changed it's child(2345). New object id can be 3456 and 4567 respectively. Then you changed 2345 (by iteration), but it makes no effect because your `content` is showing 3456 -> 4567

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Also, Can you add  spaces for each level  whenever we are embedding the tags?

Comment: @ankur added that as explanation. I will further suggest you to play with `object_id` of nodes to get more clarity.